# Java - Distinguishing Between Runnable Thread Types

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

**Context:**

I have a task where I must let "leaders" and "followers" concurrently match with each other in order to partner up for a dance. There are several dances, several leaders, and several followers. The basic idea is that a leader can only request a dance from one follower at a time. However, many leaders can ask for dances from different followers at the same time. Followers can only accept or decline requests from leaders. They cannot make requests of their own. Each dance can and should have many leader-follower pairs but the same leader shouldn't have more than 1 follower for a given dance and a follower shouldn't agree to dance with more than 1 leader for a given dance.

**Attempted Solution:**

The way I went about doing this is to make a `Leader` and `Follower` class that both implement `Runnable`.

Then in my main `Dance` class's `main()` method, I spawned `Leader` and `Follower` threads.
The way I store matches is with a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>`. This CHM exists inside the class definition of both Leader.java and Follower.java. The CHM stores the name of the dance as a key and the threadID of the follower that agrees to the dance (In Leader.java).

**Problem:**
I'm confused by how the Leader threads and Follower threads can communicate with each other, especially since the only identifying info about the threads I have is the thread's ID. Each of these threads contain an instance of the Leader and Follower class respectively, but I'm not sure how I can get these objects to "talk".

For example, how can the leaders "send" their CHM to the Follower class so that an instance of Follower can reply to it appropriately?

**Code:**
*Dance.java:*

```
public class Dance{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int nLeaders = 0;
        int mFollowers = 0;
        // Take in program args from command line and pass them to local vars so we can store them
        try {
            nLeaders = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            mFollowers = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Please make sure you have provided valid args for N and M");
        }
        // Spawn the specified number of leader/follower threads according to args
        for(int i = 1; i <= nLeaders; ++i){
            Thread spawnedLeaderThread = new Thread(new Leader()); // creates instances of our Leader class as threads
            spawnedLeaderThread.start(); // Starts all the threads we just created in the loop
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= mFollowers; ++i){
            Thread spawnedFollowerThread = new Thread(new Follower()); // creates instances of our Leader class as threads
            spawnedFollowerThread.start(); // Starts all the threads we just created in the loop
        }

    }
}
```

*Leader.java:*

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

class Leader implements Runnable{
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> leaderCHM = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    // K,V = String for Dance Type (D1, D2, etc.), Integer for Follower threadID
    public Leader(){
        leaderDC.put("D1", -1); // Initialize all the keys (dance types) with -1 (match not found yet) to be later set according to matched leaders
        leaderDC.put("D2", -1);
        leaderDC.put("D3", -1);
        leaderDC.put("D4", -1);
        leaderDC.put("D5", -1);
        leaderDC.put("D6", -1);
        leaderDC.put("D7", -1);
        leaderDC.put("D8", -1);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Spawning a Leader Thread w/ID of " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " and name of " + threadName); // Prints out the id of this current thread
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Caught a thread exception in Leader.java");
        }
    }
}
```

*Follower.java*

```
class Follower implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Spawning a Follower Thread w/ID of " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " and name of " + threadName); // Prints out the id of this current thread
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Caught a thread exception in Follower.java");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `Dance` you could have a concurrent collection to which you add all `Follower`s and then pass that collection to each `Leader`. Then add a method to `Follower` which allows requesting a dance (e.g. `boolean requestDance()`). The `ConcurrentHashMap` in `Leader` might not be needed, but this also depends on which additional actions (dancing?) `Leader` and `Follower` have to perform.

Comment: Are you doing this with threads because it is an assignment? This would seem easier to do with normal programming.

Comment: @Marcono1234 the only functionality is to find matches between followers and leaders without partners (for a given dance, of which there are a few). I think I see what you mean with the concurrent collection. If it was declared in Dance, then both Leader and Followers would be able to access it.

Comment: @NomadMaker  yes it is. It would definitely be easier without concurrency.